# Impossible to snap to objects

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to snap two objects with closest vertex, but when the vertex of the object I move is very close, it jumps back! I guess the distance is 15 mm. When it jumps back, a small ring is visible at the other objects vertex. I cant find any solution and need help!

Comment: I can't really picture your scene, but try hiding the second object that is getting in the way be selecting it and hitting H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

1: In Edit mode select the vertice you want to use as the snap point.

2: Move the 3D cursor to this vertice, (**Shft S** to open the snap menu, then choose  **Cursor to Selected**).

3: In Object mode move origin to the 3D cursor, (**Shft Ctrl Alt C** and choose the **Origin to 3D Cursor** option).

4: Change the **Snap Target** from Closest to **Active**.

In the example gif below, I’m trying to snap the point of the pyramid object to one of the corner vertices of the cube object.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I found a similar solution that works fine, in step 4: Selection to cursor.